# Agent development environement

Tags: raspbian, software-development

I am trying to develop a multi agent system using Raspberry Pi to work as an intelligent management system. Agents will use to get sensor data, time available and priorities and then decision making by a controlling agent.

I tried to find a suitable development kit for Rpi. But I could not. MaDKit, SPADE were checked.

Is there a good open source tool for developing a multi agent system on Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer : You can use JADE (it is based on JAVA and it is big framework) but you must use something like Pi4J to control GPIO in JAVA, for managing priority there isn't any direct implementation to do that, because it is not in MAS specifications (FIPA...) you must extend the framework like so : http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4053000/

Long answer : I work currently in developing an Real time Multi Agent Framework based on python and in couple of month it will be available in Git hub as open source project "COPDAI", but If you can Explain why MaDKit and SPADE wasn't enough for you I will try to help your.

Comment: I edited the question, hope it will give you an idea what I am going to do.

Comment: when you say : "time available and priorities and then decision making by a controlling agent" you mean you want manage priority between agents ?

Comment: NO, not priorities between agents. priorities are used for physical areas in my system

Comment: for managing priority there isn't any direct implementation to do that, because it is not in MAS specifications (FIPA...) you must extend the framework like so : http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4053000/